# C# вылетает ошибка "Отношение не существует"

Tags: c#, sql

Не могу разобраться с данной проблемой. Программа выпадает с ошибкой: `отношение "USERS" не существует` хотя данная таблица существует в БД и запрос вставленный в SQL менеджер успешно выполняется.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
 public void selectDataForSync() //data from PG that whould be insert in SQLLITE
    {

        UserData ud;
        List<UserData> uds = new List<UserData>();

        NpgsqlConnection conn =
             new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
                                  "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";");            

        conn.Open();

        string SQLrequest = @"SELECT guid, username, ""FL"", id, userblob FROM ""USERS"" WHERE ""FL""=10;";
        Console.WriteLine(SQLrequest);
        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(SQLrequest, conn);

        try
        {

            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader(); // here exception
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // UserData ud = new UserData();
                ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
                ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
                ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
              //  uds.Add(ud);
                //File.WriteAllBytes("outputimg.jpg", ud.userblob);
                //Console.ReadKey();

                sqllite.insertDataFromPGToSQLLite(ud);
            }
            dr.Dispose(); // releases conenction

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SelectDataForSync function");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Я пробовал указывать схему -- не помогло:
`string SQLrequest = @"SELECT guid, username, ""FL"", id, userblob FROM public.""USERS"" WHERE ""FL""=10;";`

[image: Отношение не существует]

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать схему: `SELECT guid, username, ""FL"", id, userblob FROM public.""USERS""` (скорее всего схема public, но если нет, подставьте свою).

Comment: Пробовал, тоже самое.

Comment: Вы в `ConnectionString` не указали базу